# Given a ParameterizedType, how do I create an instance of this type?

Tags: java, reflection

I am retrieving a ParameterizedType object from Field.getGenericType(), and I would like to create an instance of this type.  This type might represent, for example, a HashMap.

I thought maybe I could cast it to a Class and then use newInstance(), but that caused a ClassCastException.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ParameterizedType pType = ..;
((Class) pType.getRawType()).newInstance();
```

But you don't need the parameterized type for that - you can simple use `field.getType()`. Use `ParameterizedType` in case you want to create an instance of one of the type arguments.